# Creating documentation for third-party java library

Tags: java, eclipse, api, javadoc

We rely on some third-party java libraries (no source code available) which don't provide javadocs. Is there a practical way to create a javadoc jar for these libraries that I can use in Eclipse?

Comment: You just want to pull out the methods and their arguments?

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah I suppose if I could create a skeleton of the code to add the javadocs to, that could work.

Comment: Eclipse already does so, the best it can (try autocompletion in one of the API methods). What specifically do you want that it does not already provide?

Comment: @Raedwald I'd rather not have to build the skeleton myself, method by method